# HOW to Pass parameters to tomcat in ubuntu?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, cruisecontrol

I am trying to configure cruisecontrol to use Tomcat rather than Jetty as its servlet engine. I am following a tutorial on this and I'm stuck at the point where it says:

> Pass startup parameter to tomcat.
>
> `-Ddashboard.config=/home/cruisecontrol/work/dashboard-config.xml`

Which file do I put this in in my Tomcat installation? Is it the startup.sh file in the Tomcat directory?

The tutorials are [here](http://wiki.foochal.org/index.php/CruiseControl_FAQ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This probably needs to go in the JAVA_OPTS variable, in the catalina.sh file.

Comment: which should be added at a top-most position in catalina.sh

Comment: Or, the usual way, `export JAVA_OPTS=-Ddashboard.config=/home/cruisecontrol/work/dashboard-config.xml` before starting catalina.sh, or even `JAVA_OPTS=-Ddashboard.config=/home/cruisecontrol/work/dashboard-config.xml catalina.sh`. My point is DO NOT edit catalina.sh

Answer (score 0):

You have to have config.xml with every appserver like tomcat and weblogic. You can pass the startup parameters as mentioned there in config.xml of tomcat server.

Answer (score 0):

With Tomcat 7, this should be set in `$CATALINA_BASE/bin/setenv.sh` as stated in the `catalina.sh` script.